# Can we connect external Bluetooth Dongle in Android Tablet?

Tags: usb, bluetooth

For my survey I want to attach an external USB Bluetooth Dongle to an Android Tablet. Actually I want better range of the bluetooth, so I will use an antenna for the external bluetooth. I want to know :

1. Which Android version supports it?
2. Can an external Bluetooth work if the Tablet already has an internal Bluetooth ?
3. Any suggestion of Android Tablet in the market ?

Comment: As far as I know, Only Custom ROM's like CM10 support External USB Dongles (Till ICS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are able to connect an external Bluetooth Dongle to the Android device, it ought to work for you, even with an intrnal Bluetooth present.

Android devices with OS v3.1 and above shall support USB host capabilities. So, it is advisable to experiment with devices with the above operating systems. However, it will be on your end to make the dongle work for you; i.e. by creating a separate application for the same.

Comment: As written in Android Developers website [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/index.html) "USB accessory and host modes are directly supported in Android 3.1 (API level 12) or newer platforms. USB accessory mode is also backported to Android 2.3.4 (API level 10) as an add-on library to support a broader range of devices."
Is USB OTG (USB On The Go) a supplement to that hosting capability? What is USB OTG anyway? [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_On-The-Go) .

Comment: @Darkpain: USB On-The-Go defines portable devices which can act as USB masters. So, in the situation you are trying to tackle, the Android Tablet will act as a USB-OTG device.

Comment: and by masters, I meant the host device, which will allow connecting other USB devices for data transfer to it.